# How to write bash script that extracts characters that appear immediately after a specified pattern?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm writing a bash script that extracts JIRA ticket numbers from various text entries.. what I need is to do something like this:

If the text is:
`"blahblahblahblahTEST-123 blah blah blah"`

it will return only the number `"123"`..

The script needs to detect when the pattern `"TEST-"` appears and then extract the numbers immediately after that pattern, and only those numbers.. in this case it would cut off everything after the "123". It needs to be flexible enough that it can return any length of numbers (ie. not just 3 digits, but it would work if it's 4 digits or 5 digits or 2 digits or whatever).

I assume the answer is something with regex's but those were never my strong suit.

Comment: if you want to read up on bash [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) you can build your script from this documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Code**

```
#! /bin/bash
input="blahblahblahblahTEST-123 blah blah blah"
prefix="TEST"
[[ $input =~ $prefix\-([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

**Output**

`123`

I've set a `$prefix`variable and, assign to it the value then you want to find as an prefix to your number value.

So, you perform a simple match by using `bash regex` and print the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='blahblahblahblahTEST-123 blah blah blah'
[[ $s =~ TEST-([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

123
```